# IntelliJ inspection error on MatAutocomplete

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-material, intellij-inspections

When using a material autocomplete (from angular-material 7.3.7), I always get an inspection error from IntelliJ. Code example:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option>foobar</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The inspection error as shown from IntelliJ:

[image: matAutocomplete inspection error]

Specifically, the part `[matAutocomplete]="auto"` triggers an inspection error of the type `AngularInvalidExpressionResultType`.

Since the example is directly copied from [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) and also custom code shows the same error, I'm starting to wonder if this is really an error or just a bug in the inspection.

The `[autocomplete]`-Input expects a type `MatAutocomplete`, which is provided, and so the error description doesn't even make sense.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ?

My IntelliJ version: `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) / Build #IU-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019`

Comment: I am in `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4` and I cannot reproduce this with the code you have given. Maybe try playing with your intellij version, or you need to change something in your settings, but the code you have looks right.

Comment: can't recreate in `#IU-191.7479.19` with `"@angular/material": "7.3.7"` using exactly same code. If the issue persists after caches invalidation (*File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*), please create a support ticket

Comment: @lena After invalidating caches and a restart, the problem is gone, thank you very much! I'd vote your comment as accepted answer if I could :-)

Comment: great, thanks for update:)